# Set image max-width and max-heigth 100% but allow the image to scale larger than 100% of itself

Tags: javascript, css, image, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to scale an image to 100% of it's parent. The aspect ratio of the image should stay the same, so the 100% scale should be either 100% of the width **or** 100% of the height, whichever comes first.
I've tried using

```
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
```

This works as long as the image is larger than it's container. As soon as the container becomes larger than the image, the image no longer stretches to an edge but stays at 100% of it's size.

Browser support is an issue, Ive tried flexbox with `object-fit: contain;` **but I have to support IE10**.

Consider the following:

```css
.img-container {
  border: solid red 1px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.img-container img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: solid green 1px;
}
.size1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
.size2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
}
.size3 {
  width: 650px;
  height: 650px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container size1">
 <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>

<div class="img-container size2">
 <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>

<div class="img-container size3">
 <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>
```

The images inside `.size1` and `.size2` scale correctly, but the container for `.size3` is larger than the image, this one should stretch to the edge as well.

How do I go about doing this? 
Pure CSS is preferred, but JS is not out of the question.

Comment: You can't use the image as a background of the div?

Comment: @Troyer Not of the container, but I could add another div in the container and set the image as background for that div. That might just do the trick with `background-size: contain;`

Comment: Did you try img{ width: 100%; }

Comment: I guess using background-image on a div inside img-container  will be fine.

Comment: @TahirShahzad This does indeed work, but introduces different problems (I need to read out the size of image via javascript). So I prefer an answer with an <img> over a div with a background image

Comment: In that case, can we try to set width, height of image using javascript/jquery?

Comment: @TahirShahzad CSS is preferred, but JS is also allowed, so yes

Comment: @timo check my solution in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this solution using jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('img').each(function(){
  let imgHeight = $(this).height();
  let containerHeight = $(this).closest('.img-container').height();
  if(imgHeight > containerHeight){
    $(this).css('width','auto');
    $(this).css('height', '100%');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.img-container {
  border: solid red 1px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: solid green 1px;
}
.size1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
.size2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
}
.size3 {
  width: 650px;
  height: 650px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-container size1">
 <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>

<div class="img-container size2">
 <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>

<div class="img-container size3">
 <img src="https://www.google.nl/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>
```